# Import empty strings in BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have gz CSV files containing empty strings. When I import in BQ I get all these empty strings as NULL, while I actually need them as empty string.

A row in my CSV file looks like:

```
ip,aahsjjjja,,,,u,opera,x11,pc,2016-06-13,2016-06-13,1,1,1
```

I need 3th, 4th and 5th columns to be empty rather than NULL.

Any suggestions how to do this during the import?

Thanks in advance! 
Let me know if I can provide more info.

Best,
Galina

Comment: Is the file located in GCS? If so, you could load it by using federated sources and transform the field(s) in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [configuration.load.quote](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.quote) property of configuration for [Load Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs):

> the value that is used to quote data sections in a CSV file. BigQuery
>   converts the string to ISO-8859-1 encoding, and then uses the first
>   byte of the encoded string to split the data in its raw, binary state.
>   The default value is a double-quote ('"'). If your data does not
>   contain quoted sections, set the property value to an `empty string`

To be clear - your example row should look like below

```
ip,aahsjjjja,"","","",u,opera,x11,pc,2016-06-13,2016-06-13,1,1,1
```

Comment: Note that changing the quote character won't change how BQ interprets these fields: they'll still be loaded as null.

Comment: i didn't get your comment. you just repeated same suggestion in your answer :o)

Comment: oh, I see  - you thought i am suggesting change of quote charachter? no - i just pointed that it can be used in loaded csv

Answer (score 1):

When converting CSV, BQ interprets the empty string as null, and `""` as the non-null empty string. If you have control over how your CSV is generated, you can replace the empty string with `""` to get the desired result.

Another alternative is to load the data as you do right now, and then run a query to clean up the data. Something like:

```
SELECT ..., IFNULL(x, "") x, ...
FROM table
```

The downsides are that this adds another step to your ingestion, and you'll pay for the extra query.

Comment: This is what I first considered doing, but the size and number of tables are very large, so I was hoping to avoid this extra querying costs. However, it appears that this is unavoidable. Thank you all!